# Unable to kill the recursion with return functions

Tags: java, recursion

I am in situation where I'm trying to use recursion within a function with double return type. I actually want to display 49 using recursion but it displays 10. I'm not able to understand the mechanism behind this. From what I understood after debugging, the counter function callback itself because of the return values in its backlog and hence goes back to the value 10 instead of just displaying 49. I am not sure of a workaround with this kind of situation. Code describing my problem is presented below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 10;
    counter(i);
    System.out.print(i);
}

public static int counter(int i){
    i++;
    if(i < 50)
        counter(i);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: You actually have to return `counter(i)`. Also, you do nothing with the return value of `counter(i)` in your `main`, you just print the old `i`, which is 10...

Comment: even If do:
int j = counter(i); System.out.print(j);
it prints 11 @AndrewL.

Comment: Of course it does because you're not doing the recursion right.

Comment: [This](https://ideone.com/iUxMbJ) is what you are looking for, and it will output 50. [Here's](https://ideone.com/ZuSj4a) a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the returned values to i. You pass the value of i, not a reference to it, so updating it in the method doesn't update i in the scope of the caller.

```
public static void main( String[] args)
{
    int i = 10;
    i = counter(i);
    System.out.print(i);
}

public static int counter(int i){
    i++;
    if(i < 50)
        i = counter(i);
    return i;
}
```